# The requested URL /index.php was not found on this server

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

I know this question seems duplicate but it is not. Actually I have strange problem that I want to fix since last two days. I have install the apache2 on ubuntu 12.04, configure it and it works fine. Problem is that when I try to access the same website from other computer it opens the directory instead of website and If I click on some link it says the sentence that I wrote in the heading. Now want to know that what I am missing as all things goes fine on local PC by localhost/

I built the application in ZEND.

Comment: what is the URL that you are trying to

Comment: Computer IP address 192.168.15.122/<application name>

Comment: are you using virtual host? if you are using zend then the url should be something like 192.168.15.122/<application name>/public/index.php right?